# JQuery : How to know if input type is not radio

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

Can anyone help me with a JQuery syntax issue?

This test works fine:

```
if ( $('input[name="'+ Field +'"]').is((':radio')) ) { do something }
```

But, I would like to test if the input is **NOT** radio and, honestly, I'm struggling.

Sorry for my poor English.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( $('input[name="'+ Field +'"]').is(':not(:radio)')) { do something }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just negate the condition :

```
if ( ! $('input[name="'+ Field +'"]').is(':radio') ) //check the bang at the start
```

You could also use `:not` but it's slower :

```
if ( $('input[name="'+ Field +'"]').is(':not(:radio)') )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just seems easier without jQuery

```
if ( document.getElementsByName(Field)[0].type != 'radio' ) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are good

> if ( ! $('input[name="'+ Field +'"]').is(':radio') ) { do something }

and

> if ( $('input[name="'+ Field +'"]').is(':not(:radio)')) ) { do something }

Didn't try the javascript option, suppose it works too ;)

You save my day thank you all for your very quick answers.